# CollectionView not displaying

Tags: maui, mobile-development

I put together a CollectionView in .Net Maui for an application I am developing and this morning it wouldn't populate the page at all. I've been trying a bunch of random code tweaks but can't figure out what's going on.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsLayout="VerticalList" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference SchedyPage}, Path=ReportList}">


        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="custom:Report">
                <Frame Margin="10">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" Padding="5" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">
                               
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding address, TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding pickupTime,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="Company"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding company,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="Type"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding pickupType,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="Requestor"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="{Binding requestor,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="Contact"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="{Binding driver,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="{Binding driverPhone,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="Manager"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="{Binding manager,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                Text="{Binding managerPhone,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Border
                            BackgroundColor="MediumPurple">
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding inventory,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                  BackgroundColor="white"/>
                            </Border>

                        </VerticalStackLayout>




                        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="5" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding locationNo,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding city,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding zipcode,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Border Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    Padding="2,2,2,2">

                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding state,TargetNullValue=''}"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold">

                                </Label>
                            </Border>

                            <Button Text="Note" Margin="5"
                                    Clicked="OpenNotes">
                                    
                            </Button>
                            <Button Text="Sign" Margin="5"
                                    Clicked="OpenSignature">
                                
                            </Button>
                            
                        </VerticalStackLayout>


                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        
        
        
        
        
    </CollectionView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, can provide more information if necessary

I've tried setting it as a listView and switched it back after no results. I expected it to display a number of Reports I've extracted from a different file.

Comment: please post the VM code

Comment: check this sample https://github.com/imoulas/sample-maui-net-expense-app